# JavaScript SDK-based workflow never pushes message back from OAuth login_success page on Stack Exchange side

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, javascript, oauth2

I'm using the [JavaScript SDK by Stack Exchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) provided with the latest API, and despite following the official instructions & examples it doesn't work - it seems there is a bug which breaks the workflow, and I believe it's on Stack Exchange's side.

The issue is that `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` never gets information about success/error of the authorization workflow, it just stays on the "Authorizing Application" step, never going further.

Further investigations show a Chrome Console output showing us a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined` jQuery error on Stack Exchange's login_success page:

```
login_success?assisted=8723&protocol=https&proxy=https://zendesk.mvink.me/integrations/stackexchang…:122 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (login_success?assisted=8723&protocol=https&proxy=https://zendesk.mvink.me/integrations/stackexchang…:122)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ login_success?assisted=8723&protocol=https&proxy=https://zendesk.mvink.me/integrations/stackexchang…:122
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
K @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Looking into the source code, it seems you are using `$.browser.msie && $.browser.version` which [has been deprecated in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed), and you are currently using jQuery 1.12 on this page.

```
// IE technically supports postMessage, but does a *really* bad job of it
if (window.postMessage && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= '9.0')) {
    // modern browsers
    window.opener.postMessage(window.location.hash, 'https://zendesk.mvink.me');
} else {
```

The result is - success action is never passed to the host window (the one auth process has been called from), so it's not possible to get an access token back.

Please have a look into this.

Comment: Confirmed. And even [SE's demo login](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib#login-button) fails with `$.browser is undefined`.

Comment: This happened to me a few weeks ago and even adding the jquery migrate plugin to add browser didn't work. I thought it was a problem with my script but it seems not now. :/ This seems to be related to SE changing their jquery version maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

This has been fixed; for example you can see that [the login demo](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib#login-button) is working properly again.