# Stack Exchange Javascript SDK implicit OAuth2 bugs in `SE.authenticate`

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, oauth2

I've tried to set up an implicit [authorization workflow with JavaScript SDK](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) version 2.0:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js'></script>
```

I was using `localhost` with other parameters set up properly. Two bugs related to `SE.authenticate` appeared:

### 1. Users who have not logged in before get stuck at `login_success`

After the user enters his login/password at `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?...`, he encounters:

```
Application Login Failure
An error occurred while login into an application.

Error Details

error description: could not parse proxy url
```

at another [`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?...`](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=11245&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com%2Foauth%2Flogin_success%3Fassisted%3D11245%26protocol%3Dhttp%26proxy%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fempty.html&scope=&response_type=token&state=2&returnurl=%2Foauth%2Fdialog%3Fclient_id%3D11245%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%252foauth%252flogin_success%253fassisted%253d11245%2526protocol%253dhttp%2526proxy%253dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25252Fempty.html%26scope%3D%26response_type%3Dtoken%26state%3D2).

**Solution:** Clicking on "Run Example With Version" (the one that calls `SE.authenticate`) button again. The second time, being logged in, it redirects properly and authorizes the client.

**Related:**

- [JavaScript SDK-based workflow never pushes message back from OAuth login_success page on Stack Exchange side](https://stackapps.com/questions/7168/javascript-sdk-based-workflow-never-pushes-message-back-from-oauth-login-success)
- [Implicit OAuth flow is not working when the user is not logged in.](https://stackapps.com/questions/3141/implicit-oauth-flow-is-not-working-when-the-user-is-not-logged-in)
- [OAuth redirect not completing](https://stackapps.com/questions/3156/oauth-redirect-not-completing)

### 2. `SE.authenticate` ignores the port

I run `index.html` with Stack Exchange authentication on `localhost:8080`. Bug 1 appears again. But now calling `SE.authenticate` second time doesn't work. The process stops on [`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?...`](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?assisted=11245&protocol=http&proxy=http://localhost:8080/empty.html#access_token=__TOKEN__&state=3&expires=86399) page saying `Authorizing Application`.

The console says:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:8080').
```

**Solution:** Switching back to `localhost(:80)`.

**Related:**

- [Javascript SDK channelUrl for local development](https://stackapps.com/questions/4733/javascript-sdk-channelurl-for-local-development) (solved, not fixed)

### Solutions

These solutions don't address the issues directly. The problems will persist until JS SDK is fixed.

Comment: I have similar issues it seems. I am using apache Oltu library to setup the oauth code flow, the authorization code is being requested. But the redirection url is:  https://localhost/seredirect/?code="code". if I manually add localhost:8444 then the whole workflow gets completed. How do I solve this problem?